# Adding data to react state using spread syntax but the first select does not update on selectedData state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am building my frontend using React. I want when the user selects a bank it will be added to the `selectData` state, but it is not working as expected. When the user is selects a bank for the first time it does not add to the `selectedData` state but if the user select the second time it is added to the state.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export const terr = () => {
    const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState({})
    const onChange = (value) => {
        console.log(`selected ${value}`);

        setSelectedData({
            ...selectedData,
            "bank_code": value
        });
        console.log(`selected data ${selectedData}`);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Form.Item
                label="Bank Name"
                name="bank_code"
                rules={[
                    {
                        required: true,
                        message: 'Select your bank name!',
                    },
                ]}
            >
                <Select
                    showSearch
                    placeholder="Select a Bank"
                    optionFilterProp="children"
                    onChange={onChange}
                    onSearch={onSearch}
                    filterOption={filterOption}
                    options={banks}
                />
            </Form.Item>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: React state updates are processed asynchronously, so you can ***never*** enqueue a state update and expect to console log it from the same callback scope. At least one React component render cycle must occur between the two. Don't worry, the state was updated, you are just incorrectly verifying it. Note however that it is more advisable to use a functional state update, e.g. `setSelectedData(selectedData => ({ ...selectedData, "bank_code": value }));` so the state is correctly updated from the previous state value versus whatever may be closed over in callback scope.

Answer (score 0):

In React the setState function won't update the state until the next render. To get it to update immediately you can use a callback in the setSelectedData function.

```
setSelectedData(oldData => ({
  ...oldData,
  "bank_code": value
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Within `onChange`, the object that `selectedData` is bound to doesn't change. Instead react will re-render the `terr`, and that will see the new object that you passed to `setSelectedData`, and you will have a new `onChange` that will close over it. As you note, a call to that `onChange` will see the modified `selectedData`.

If you want to observe that object, give it a name before passing it to `setSelectedData`.

```
const onChange = (value) => {
    console.log(`selected ${value}`);

    const data = {
        ...selectedData,
        "bank_code": value
    };
    setSelectedData(data);
    console.log(`selected data ${data}`);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Ant Design.
You should pass `selectedData` to `value` property of `Select`.
https://ant.design/components/select#select-props

P.S. it's better to wrap `onChange` with `useCallback` hook to avoid unnecessary re-renders of `Select` component.